# TortoiseSVN Repository Browser Not Working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, ssh-tunnel

When I search for a URL in the TortoiseSVN Repository Browser (that I know exists), it prompts me for the password for the username I have entered. However, it always says my password is denied (I know for a fact that I have the right password). After a number of attempts, I tried closing the password prompt. It takes a good 5 - 10 closes before it finally stops.

The repository browser then says

> To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.  Network connection closed unexpectedly.

To start, I didn't access this from any command line, so I'm not sure what this `-q` thing is.  Secondly, I'm not sure what this 'Subversion configuration file' is.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Is this is a common TortoiseSVN problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows Explorer, right-click on a folder, choose the `TortoiseSVN` menu from the context menu, and click `Settings`. When the dialog opens, in the `Subversion` section at the bottom, click the button labeled `Edit`. The `SVN` configuration file will open.

You'll find the section about `configuring tunnel agents` at about line 40 or so in the file (in the 32-bit version I have on `WinXP` - `TortoiseSVN 1.6.8`, which is slightly outdated).

Almost all of the lines are probably commented out (start with `###`). You'll also want to look at the first section (`authentication and authorization customizations`).

For information about configuring Subversion, you should look at the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) - the free book (PDF or HTML formats) tells you pretty much everything you need to know about configuring and using SVN.

Comment: I found the -q option and removed it, but I'm still having the same problem.  Any further ideas?

Comment: Read the section at the top of the file (authentication). It discusses existing password removal. You've provided no information about how your server or repository are configured, so all I can suggest is that you a) talk to the person who administers your repository/SVN configuration, and b) download and check the SVN book; there's a troubleshooting section. Don't know if it will help or not.

Comment: This location in the TortoiseSVN settings dialog has changed. On the left side, midway, find 'Network' and then in the Network tab look for 'Subversion server file'. Unfortunately I do not see the place to remove the -q